# Creating a numeric phone keypad

Tags: java, enums, abstract

I'm writing a Telephone class and it has a method called getDigits which takes in a String parameter and returns the number that would appear on your phone if you typed in those letters the old fashioned way. Ex- Typing in "CAT" would return 227. I wrote the following code and it works but I wanted to know if anyone else out there had better ideas to do it/ more sophisticated ones. I'm learning about data abstraction/enums and such and feel like I should be using them but I just can't figure out how to implement it here. Any help appreciated:

```
public int getDigits(String test){
        String result = "";
        String param = test.toUpperCase();
        for(int i = 0; i<param.length(); i++){
            String s = Character.toString(param.charAt(i));
            if(s.equals("A") || s.equals("B") || s.equals("C")){
                result += 2;
            }

            else if(s.equals("D") || s.equals("E") || s.equals("F")){
                result += 3;
            }

            else if(s.equals("G") || s.equals("H") || s.equals("I")){
                result += 4;
            }

            else if(s.equals("J") || s.equals("K") || s.equals("L")){
                result += 5;
            }

            else if(s.equals("M") || s.equals("N") || s.equals("O")){
                result += 6;
            }

            else if(s.equals("P") || s.equals("Q") || s.equals("R") || s.equals("S")){
                result += 7;
            }
            else if(s.equals("T") || s.equals("U") || s.equals("V")){
                result += 8;
            }

            else if(s.equals("W") || s.equals("X") || s.equals("Y") || s.equals("Z")){
                result += 9;
            }
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(result);
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it's about determining any possible ways to improve working code. You might have better luck on [CodeReview.SE], but be sure to read their help center before you post it there.

Comment: Yeah, this belong on code review

Comment: @EvanCarslake Sure, but I'd warmly recommend taking out or rewording the part about needing help figuring out enums.